# How to combine PDF documents to make a new document using Preview?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, pdf, preview, combine

Preview lets me combine pages from different documents into one window, but I can't find a way to save the resulting multi-page document.  Preview displays `Untitled (1 page) (3 documents, 3 total pages)`.  I would like it to combine these pages into `(1 document, 3 total pages)`.  I thought I could just click Save As, but that merely renamed a single page.  Is there a way to do this with Preview?  If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drag the other documents into the new document. From the page thumbnail view, click the arrow to open your main document, and then drag the pages you want to add to somewhere within that document. You'll see something like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Preview sidebar.]

Then just save the document normally.

Alternatively, you can use the print function to print all of the documents in one job, and just save it as a PDF. That's a bit counter-intuitive, though.

Comment: I didn't understand your steps for combining the documents once they were in the page thumbnail view, but the PDF printing method worked.  Could you flesh out how you got that rounded corners oval with the fancy red circle with a 2 in it?  **Update:  nevermind,  I see how it works.  Thanks a bunch!**

Comment: Be sure that you drag it in and have the blue box with rounded corners show. If it doesn't you're not merging the PDFs. (I don't understand what does happen if you don't have the blue box).